# Run in development mode in web project

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring MVC Project based on maven build tool. In my application, I have to make web-service calls to external server for some data. I have implemented it and it all works well.

But in the development mode, I would rather want to avoid them. So currently I have

`public static boolean devel = false`

I use above boolean with `if else` statements so that if under development mode, then provide static data. If not development mode then make web-service calls.

But I find this boolean declaration dirty. In the sense that, I manually have to correct the boolean in my code every time I deploy it in production. And once I forgot to that causing havoc.

Is there any decent way? I would not like to have this variable declared in the code but from some constant obtained during build process or probably some VM argument. Or they might even be a better way. If so, how I incorporate it in my spring-maven project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is have code default to production behavior so something like, have the bool devel comes from a properties file. The default value in the classpath = false and 
and in order to override it I would use something like:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
            <value>${external-config}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

on my dev machine I run  my application with

```
-Dexternal-config=file:/c:/debug.properties
```

that properties file holds some placeholder that overrides values stored in config.properties located in the jar/war

Answer (score 1):

What I would consider a "decent way" (as you term it) is to use *dependency injection*; using either [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) or Java [CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjban.html) features. This is exactly the type of scenario, that dependency injection is useful for.

You would then declare an interface, which is implemented by two different classes:

1. the real class - that connects to the remote server, and
2. a development/test class that returns static data.

Your launch configuration would then determine which of the two classes gets injected into your application.

Answer (score 1):

Spring (3.1+) supplies a way to specify a @Profile, which can be used in conjunction with @Configuration annotations. Have a look at http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/

Using that methology, you can create your own configuration beans per environment (production, development, staging, etc)